# Dimensions of velocity vector in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, dimensional-analysis

If we have a velocity vector written in, say, cartesian coordinates:

$\mathbf V$ = $\dot{x}$  **i** $+$ $\dot{y}$ **j**

Note that Dim($\dot{x}$) = Dim($\dot{y}$) = $LT^{-1}$ which are the dimensions of speed and Dim(**i**) $=$ Dim (**j**) $= 1$ (i.e. dimensionless since they are unit vectors). Thus we have the totally expected result that the dimensions of velocity are $LT^{-1}$. Moreover, we have a straightforward interpretation of the components of this vector as being the speed of the (say) particle in the x and y directions respectively.

Going to the differential geometry setting we write our vector as:

$\mathbf V =A\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + B\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

I write $A$ and $B$ because I no longer know how to interpret the components, this is because the dimensions of the partial derivative operators are (seemingly) $L^{-1}$ as opposed to the dimensionless basis vectors we had above. But this means that $A$ and $B$ must have dimensions of $L^{2}T^{-1}$ for the velocity vector as a whole to have the correct dimensions. So what is going on here? Can we no longer interpret the components of this vector as we did above? Also please clarify the issue for the two cases where our manifold has and doesn't have a metric because I suspect if you do have a metric you can somehow normalize the vectors (for instance defining a new basis vector which equals $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ divided by $\sqrt{(g_{11}})$ would take care of the issue I think but i'm not entirely sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a curve $\gamma: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathcal M$ where $\mathcal M$ is the manifold under consideration (in your case, presumably $\mathbb R^2$), we define the tangent vector to $\gamma$ at the point $p=\gamma(0)$ to be a map $\mathcal V_{\gamma,p}$ which eats smooth functions $f:\mathcal M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and spits out the following number:

$$\mathcal V_{\gamma,p} (f) = (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$$

In other words, a tangent vector is a *directional derivative operator* associated to some curve at some point.  It eats a function and spits out the rate at which that function changes along the associated curve.  Therefore, if we interpret the curve parameter as time, then tangent vectors have dimension $\mathrm T^{-1}$.

In a coordinate chart where $\gamma(t) = \big(x(t),y(t)\big)$, we have

$$V_{\gamma,p}(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x'(0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y'(0) \iff V_{\gamma,p} = x'(0) \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + y'(0) \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$
If the coordinates $(x,y)$ have dimensions of $\mathrm L$, then the **components** of the vector in this basis have dimensions of $\mathrm{LT}^{-1}$, and the basis vectors themselves have dimensions of $\mathrm L^{-1}$.

---

Your mistake lies in the following line:

> But this means that A and B must have dimensions of $L^2 T^{-1}$ for the velocity vector as a whole to have the correct dimensions.

You are assuming that the velocity vector has dimensions of $\mathrm L \mathrm T^{-1}$, but in fact the correct dimensions of a directional derivative operator are $\mathrm T^{-1}$ (again, assuming that the curve parameter has dimensions of $\mathrm T$).

> Also please clarify the issue for the two cases where our manifold has and doesn't have a metric

The presence or absence of a metric has no bearing on this issue.  You can *always* define new dimensionless coordinates $\tilde x = x/x_0$ and $\tilde y = y/y_0$.  However, the dimensions of a tangent vector are $\mathrm T^{-1}$ *regardless* of your coordinates (which should be obvious, since the definition of the tangent vector is coordinate-free), and so making this redefinition will yield velocity components with dimensions of $\mathrm T^{-1}$.  I suspect this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer now. One small issue though: It seems to me then that the velocity vector as we use it in classical mechanics is actually coordinate dependent no? Also your reasoning applies to other things like Force fields for example yes? of course now this is a map from the manifold to the tangent bundle but I mean the dimensional analysis still applies: if we take our coordinates to have dimensions of length then a force vector will have dimensions of $T^-{2}M$ where M is dimensions of mass, regardless of coordinate correct?

Comment: One thing I noticed in the above example is that the dimensions of length cancelled away just like in the velocity vector case. Now that I think about it, it makes sense: If our coordinates have dimensions of length any dependence on length would inevitably lead to a coordinate dependent description yes? Because by definition it would depend on the choice of unit length that we impose on our coordinate charts.

Comment: @Leonid I'm not entirely sure I understand the question(s).  What do you mean by a "coordinate-dependent description"?  A tangent vector is a coordinate-independent object.  If you pick some coordinates and a basis, you can expand it in components.  These components will of course depend on the coordinates you choose.

Comment: @Leonid A vector (or vector field) can have whatever dimensions you'd like.  There's no reason, for instance, that we need to interpret the curve parameter as having dimensions of time.  The point of this answer is simply to demonstrate that the *components* of a tangent vector will generically have different dimensions than the tangent vector itself, depending on the dimensions of the basis you chose.

Comment: Let me clarify my statement a bit: In classical mechanics we say that velocity has dimensions of length per time and interpret it as being "the rate of change of the position vector -- consisting of coordinate functions -- with respect to time", that's how we get the dimensions to be length per time in the first place. But notice that this definition depends on the choice of coordinate functions (which can look very different in different charts), that's what I mean that the definition used is coordinate dependent. Not sure if that clarified but in any case I got your point so thanks.